# Деплой full-stack проекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, nestjs

Всем привет.

Есть готовый проект с бэкендом (`nestjs` + `mongodb`) и фронтэндом (`next`).

Хочу задеплоить на платный хостинг, я в этом деле очень слабо понимаю. Уже второй день ищу, не могу найти какой то нормальной информации. В каком направлении мне копать?

Может у кого-то есть решение.